# Incomplete Eclipse-generated Javadoc

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a 20-30 class project in Eclipse which I completely commented for Javadoc, and when I run the built-in Javadoc Generator, Eclipse gives me no errors. However the Javadoc which I obtain doesn't display many of the methods/constructors/fields of some of the classes. It seems completely arbitrary--in some cases all but a few of the methods are displayed, in other cases no fields are displayed whatsoever, and so on.

I cannot post any of my code here, but I was wondering if anyone ever encountered a similar problem, or has any ideas as to what could be causing this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are the missing methods/fields protected or private? There are switches/controls to exclude non-public methods and fields in JavaDoc (protected and private can be independently turned on/off)

Comment: Yes, you're right! Do you know where I can find these switches? You're welcome to provide an answer instead of a comment, I will mark it as best answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll go ahead and put the answer here, I could use the points. In order to generate Javadoc's in Eclipse select the project in the Project Explorer, typically on the left side of the screen. Then, under the menu item "Project" find the "Generate Javadoc" command. It will bring up the [Eclipse Javadoc Generation Wizard](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.user%2Freference%2Fref-export-javadoc.htm). The first screen of the wizard has the options for "Create Javadoc for members with visibility." See attached screenshot.

[image: First Page of Eclipse Javadoc Generation Wizard]